# How to get a Bootstrap Modal to pop up on specific WordPress page after delay

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap 4 Modal to pop up on an Order Received page after a 2-second delay on WordPress. I'm new to theme customization. This is what I have, but I can't get the HTML to print on the page.

I want to hook into: `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>` on `thankyou.php`. I also want the modal to popup on page load. The JS I found for that would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

In the Thankyou page body class, it shows `page-id-8` as the page ID.

In my `functions.php` file, I have the following:

### Questions:

1. For some reason, the HTML is not printing on the page. Any ideas on what else I can do?
2. What would be the next steps for adding a `<script></script>` tag on the same page to add a `setTimeout` function to delay it?

Code:

```
function create_modal() {
 if(is_single('8')) {
     echo '
     <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">A NOTE ON SHIPPING</h5>
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
             </button>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             <p>Thank you so much for your order! As we\'re sure you\'re aware, we are a little backed up due to COVID-19.</p> 
     
             <p>While we work hard to get your order out in a timely manner, we sincerely appreciate your understanding and patience.</p>
     
             <p>When your order ships, you\'ll receive an email with tracking information attached. Please keep an eye out for your package. Also note that FedEx and USPS are also backed up due to COVID-19, and delivery times may also be delayed.</p>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
             <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>';
 }
}

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_', 'create_modal', 10);
```

Comment: Use `is_page(8)` not, `is_single`. `is_single` is for posts.

Comment: Thank you. I have the modal working now. THanks for your help.